# Powershell loop through 2nd Octets and 4th Octets

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach, ip

First I apologize for how terrible I am with powershell.

I'm trying to loop through 2nd octet (1-254) and 4th octet (209-211) IP addresses, and return the example results below.

```
example ip (2nd octet loop though all possible, then only 4th octet 209 - 211)
10.XXX.88.209 
10.XXX.88.210 
10.XXX.88.211 

example results
10.24.88.209, ABCD0123456
10.88.88.210, ABCD0542857
10.192.88.211, ABCD0123499



$ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
$i = 0
$2octet = (1..255)
$4octet = (209..211)
foreach ($2oct in $2octet){
    foreach ($4oct in $4octet){
        foreach { $ip = "10.$2oct.11.$4oct" 
        $Res = $ping.send($ip)

        if ($Res.Status -eq "Success")
        {

        $result = $ip + " = Success"
        Write-Host $result

        $i++

        }
    }
}
 } 
$Hosts = [string]$i
Write-Host $Hosts , $ip
```

Comment: You havent stated a problem here? You inner most for loop should not be there though. I would take that out and leave the code inside alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you octets why not try something simple like

```
for($second = 1; $second -lt 256; $second++){
    for($fourth = 209; $fourth -lt 212; $fourth++){
        Write-Host "10.$second.88.$fourth"
    }
}
```

Comment: I bow down to your superior intellect and knowledge of powershell. Still working my final solution but thanks for getting me over the hump I was thinking a for loop was the answer but didn't know how to write it.

Comment: What else are you trying to accomplish? I thought fixing the loops would complete this.

Comment: I want to return the hostname and ip address of computers that exist within that range.

Comment: After checking the .Status -eq 'Success' try something like this                       if($result.Status -eq "Success"){
    $hostEntry = [Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry(IP)

    Write-Host $result.Address + ' ' + $hostEntry.HostName
}